# Asp.Net Charts - Increase bar spacing

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

Finding it hard to increase the space between the bars. Unable to find any solution that works in my case. Though the chart type is column, it shows up as a stacked column.

```
<asp:Chart ID="bcOperators" runat="server" Width="500" Height="300">                                                   
 <Series>
   <asp:Series Name="Operator" ChartType="Column" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" />
 </Series>
 <ChartAreas>
   <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
     <AxisX Interval="1" Title="Operators"></AxisX>
     <AxisY Title="Count"></AxisY>
   </asp:ChartArea>
 </ChartAreas>
```

This did not work

```
bcOperators.Series["y"].BorderWidth = 1;
bcOperators.Series["y"].BorderColor = Color.White;
```

[image]

Comment: set `CustomProperties="PointWidth=.6"` in _Series_ tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<Series>
<asp:Series Name="Operator" ChartType="Column" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" CustomProperties="PointWidth=.6" />
</Series>
```